# Excel - Counting number of occurrence in a bit string large range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I have 13-bit strings data in a column, I want to count the number of cells with unique combination of bits. The total number of cells in that column is 209066. I am stuck on how to make it possible.
Since, 2^13 = 8192 cells, so that's quite hectic too , to find the unique combinations statistically, and then write in the adjacent cell, how much times that value occurs.

```
13 Bit String   Occurrence
1001111101011   
0011111010110   
0111110101101   
1111101011011   
1111010110110   
1110101101100   
1101011011000   
1010110110000   
0101101100001   
1011011000010   
0110110000101   
1101100001011   
1011000010111   
0110000101110   
1100001011101   
1000010111011   
0000101110111   
0001011101110   
0010111011100   
0101110111001   
1011101110011   
0111011100111   
1110111001110   
1101110011101   
1011100111010   
0111001110101   
1110011101011   
1100111010110   
1001110101100   
0011101011001   
0111010110011   
1110101100110   
1101011001100   
1010110011000   
0101100110000   
1011001100001   
0110011000011   
1100110000110   
1001100001100   
0011000011001   
0110000110011   
1100001100110
.......
[continued upto cell 209066]
```

Comment: like in B2 `=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)` and then simply copy it down?

Comment: @DirkReichel, Your formula seems to work but it takes hell looooot of time to perform calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Highlight the column with the bits
2. Data--> Sort&Filter --> Advanced
3. Enable "Copy to another location" and "Unique records only" List
4. Range should be where all the bits are (already highlighted)
5. Leave Criteria Range blank
6. Copy to should be a blank cell, in the same worksheet, with nothing in the rows below it.
7. Assume bits are in column A, Unique in column D. Put this formula in E1 and fill down along the unique values `=COUNTIF($A:$A,"="&D1)`  `

Comment: that only copies the unique values to another column. I want to count the occurrence of these bits in the whole column. :(

Comment: Added a forgotten step 7. Counting them tends to help!

Comment: You Sir, You are a lifeSaver! One last thing, what if I want to copy the occurrence of the value to the first cell that is encountered in the actual bit column. Like
1001111101011 14
0011111010110 7
0111110101101 12
1111101011011 15
.....
.....
[continued]
Now, I want to copy that 14 to the first occurrence in the actual bit column, like, find the first value that matches 1001111101011  and then copy 14 in the adjacent cell.

Comment: Glad to help. Can it do it for every instance? Or just the first? For every instance in B1 use and fill down `=VLOOKUP(A1,$D:$E,2,FALSE)`. For just the first, use the same formula in B1 and then in B2 and down use `=IF(MATCH(A2,A$1:A2,0)<ROW(),"",VLOOKUP(A2,$D:$E,2,FALSE))`

Comment: Also a hint for working with such large data - before filling in the formulas, go to Formulas --> Calculation Options --> Manual. Then fill in formulas and go back to turn it to Automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Parse your data with Text to Columns, Fixed width, single character per field. Say in Columns A:M working on a copy. Then:

```
=SUM(A2:M2)
```

say in N2 and:

```
=COUNTIF(N:N,N2)
```

say in O2 with N2 and O2 copied down to suit.

Comment: he is talking about bits... this is a binary system: 1 = 1; 10 = 2; 11 = 3; 100 = 4... by summing up the bits as 1's, "10" and "01" would be the same, and that is wrong. He also could use [`BIN2DEC`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/BIN2DEC-function-63905b57-b3a0-453d-99f4-647bb519cd6c). so each "combination" of bits would get its own value... He never asks for "unique count of 1 bits"... at least the "2^13 = 8192" should have told you what he is aiming for. Your way would only give 14 different possibilities ;)

Comment: It looks like it is not 100% clear what the OP want's... (but yes, BIN2DEC is limited to 10 chars, this way, there is no use for it here... was just used as example)

Comment: If there were only the first two rows in the OP's data then each of those two values would be unique combinations of bits.  But your solution will come up with a value of 9 in both N2 and N3, and a value of 2 in O2 and O3.

Comment: Ahh - I just saw your comment to the original post and see that you are interpreting the word `combination` in a statistics sense, rather than its common usage sense.  From that point of view you are correct - you would only need to see which of the 14 possible values only occur once.  But the fact that the OP mentions 8192 possible values makes me think that he is using "combination" in a common usage sense.

Comment: The fact that there are 209066 values means that they aren't **all** unique, even if the first few are.

Comment: LOL - I guess that is true - it could be 8192 cells containing 13 Bit Strings and 200,000+ values of "Why am I counting these cells?!?!?".

Comment: No, Its 209066 cells in a column with 13-bit number in each.
8192 are the combinations of bits of numbers that can exist for a 13-bit number.
Like 2-bit number can have combinations: 00 01 10 11
3-bit as: 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111 
Only mentioned that because if I write a formula which I did for 4-bit count in the same column, I was able to find 16 combinations-which was easy.

Comment: And combination is a relative term, not the mathematical combinations :)

Answer (score 0):

After reading everything again, You are probably looking for something like this:

```
=SUM((COUNTIF(A2:A209066,A2:A209066)=1)*1)
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

Counts the each value which is unique within the range.

But you may be looking for the count of different values which is:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(1/COUNTIF(A2:A209066,A2:A209066),0))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

**EDIT**

If you just want the count for the first value, then this may be what you need (B1 and copy down):

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A2,A:A,0)=ROW(),COUNTIF(A:A,A2),""),"")
```

(no array formula this time) ;)